# FFMPEG: How can I get the first frame of an MP4 and maintain its aspect ratio?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, terminal

Trying to get every mp4 file in a directory, and batch-save out a PNG of its first frame.

I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 -vf "select=eq(n\,0)" -vframes 1 filename.png
```

When I do this, it correctly saves the first frame of each file, but they're coming out stretched into a square.

Input is 607x1080
Output is 1080x1080

Not all inputs will be the same aspect ration so I can't hard code it. I just want to preserve the aspect ration and dimensions of the original file.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the output:

```
> ffmpeg -i connecting-to-senses-explainer-1.mp4 -vf "select=eq(n\,0)" -vframes 1 output.png

ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'connecting-to-senses-explainer-1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp42iso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-10-13T22:25:00.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 1.4.2 2021100300
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 131 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1080x1080 [SAR 9:16 DAR 9:16], 128 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-13T22:25:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x1308c0000] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
Output #0, image2, to 'output.png':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp42iso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: png, rgb24(pc, bt709, progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 9:16 DAR 9:16], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-13T22:25:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 png
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.3x
video:110kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: It should work fine. Perhaps there is some issue in the SAR/DAR of the input video. You could share the output log of ffmpeg conversion. Also, if you wish to only extract the first frame as an image, you don't really need the video filter.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it? I'll edit in the output above, cheers @Rajib

Comment: For me this same command results in PNG frame same size as the original move, but the first frama of a movie is almost always a black screen....

Comment: See this part in your output: `1080x1080 [SAR 9:16 DAR 9:16]` This shows that your video is actually square 1080x1080, but is being made to display in portrait mode through SAR and DAR being 9:16.

Comment: @Rajib well that's odd! I didn't make the videos, is there a way to batch resize them (so they're actually 9:16), which in turn would solve the frame aspect ratio issue?

Comment: @llogan added the full output for you above

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your input has non-square pixels (`SAR 9:16`). ffmpeg tries to preserve aspect ratio when converting. But most image viewers naïvely ignore the Sample Aspect Ratio (SAR) and assume square pixels. Therefore the image looks stretched/squished.

You can use the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and [setsar](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setdar_002c-setsar) filters to make square pixels:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1" -vframes 1 filename.png
```

If your input already has square pixels the scale filter won't do anything. So there is no harm in using it in a loop for batch converting.