# What's a good way to encode a file name for caching a video thumbnail?

Tags: linux, bash, encoding, hashing, chafa

I'm writing a previewer script for [`lf`](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf) using `chafa` to display preview images as sixels.

I'm writing the part of the script for previewing videos, and decided to just display the first frame of the video. Here's what I currently have:

```bash
# check if cache folder exists
if [ ! -d "$cache_folder" ]; then
    mkdir "$cache_folder"
fi

# going to store thumbnail here:
# not using mktemp as chafa expects a file extension
thumbnail_file="$cache_folder/$(echo "$1" | base64).png"

# if the thumbnail isn't cached then make it:
if [ ! -f "$thumbnail_file" ]; then
    # get first frame of video:
    # https://superuser.com/a/1682482/816753
    # & suppress output so it doesn't display in the previewer
    # the below makes the pixels square in case we have non-square pixels
    # which means the image won't look stretched/squished after displaying
    # add -y to overwrite thumbnail file if exists
    ffmpeg -i "$1" -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1" -vframes 1 -y "$thumbnail_file" &>/dev/null
fi

chafa -f sixel -s "$2x$3" --animate off --polite on "$thumbnail_file"
```

As you can see, I'm encoding the file name in base64 and saving it to a cache folder so that if the video thumbnail is already cached, I can just display the cached image with `chafa` instead of having to run `ffmpeg` every time which is slow.

However for some video files, I'm getting:

```
chafa: Failed to open [thumbnail file]: File name too long
```

What would people suggest for a good way to create file names for cached thumbnails? (I am fine with my assumption that the contents of each video file won't change; if I need to update a thumbnail I can just delete it from the cache folder.) The requirements I'd have are:

- Reasonable uniqueness/unlikely for two video files to end up with the same cached file name, as obviously this would result in them having the same preview thumbnail despite being different videos
- Result in a reasonably short file name, at least so that `chafa` won't complain. (I'm not actually sure what `chafa`'s limit for file name length is; I tried looking it up but couldn't find anything.)
- Of course be a valid file name, so no `/`

Comment: As an update, I'm currently using the last 100 characters of the base64 encoding of the full file path which seems to be working well. Suggestions for better ways to do this are appreciated though

Comment: Is your current code working? What makes you believe there may be collisions? What is "reasonably short"? Does chafa document its limits? If so then just truncate your filenames. To avoid conflicts you can add date/time stamps precise enough they won't ever match. The "good way" is opinion, because there are ways that meet your needs and ways that don't. Your question strikes me as one that COULD work here, but it is phrased in a way that makes it sound you already have a solution and just want some general tips, and that sort of question is often closed because it is based on opinion.

Comment: I recommend you spend a bit of time noting the specific ways your current script falls short, using direct and specific and clear language, and then as we'll know what's not working and what you need it to do, this will be a pretty good question that will likely be well-received and could probably get a pretty good set of answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use [md5sum](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/md5sum.1.html) for this purpose. Which generates hexadecimal 128-bit hash, so that means it always has 32 characters. The chance of collision is minimal.

```
thumbnail_file="$cache_folder/$(echo -n "$1" | md5sum).png"
```

Note that this is prone to errors if you name 2 different files in the same way. To get around that, you could for example combine the file name/path with its modification time, which is extremely unlikely to have any hash conflict. That of course works only if you don't modify the files in the meanwhile, which was your assumption. E.g.:

```
modification_timestamp=$(stat -c %Y "$1")
thumbnail_file="$cache_folder/$(echo -n "${1}${modification_timestamp}" | md5sum).png"
```

Check [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) documentation for more info.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I thought the files weren't big, but no idea why reading again. I'll remove the answer.